# Windows Service can not open Windows Form

Tags: winforms, windows-services, topshelf

I am trying to create a `Windows Service` using `TopShelf` and within this service i want to launch a `Windows Form`.After i created the service and i debugged it calling `ShowDialog`  the form does not show up:

**Service**

```
 class SimpleServ {
    private Task task;
    private const string PATH = @"D:/out.txt";
    private Logger logger;
    private CancellationTokenSource src = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public SimpleServ() {
        logger = new Logger();

    }
    public void Start() {

        logger.Log("Started");
        this.task = Task.Run(async () => {

            var fm = new Fm(logger);
            while (true) {
                fm.ShowDialog();
                logger.Log("Just closed the dialog");
                await Task.Delay(3000);
            }
        });
    }
    public void Stop() {
        logger.Log("Stopped service");
    }
}
```

**Form**

```
public partial class Fm : Form {
    private Logger log;
    public Fm(Logger log) {
        this.log = log;
        this.log.Log("From Form constructor");
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.log.Log("Button clicked");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

**Main**

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x => {
                x.Service<SimpleServ>(s => {
                    s.ConstructUsing(h => new SimpleServ());
                    s.WhenStarted(h => h.Start());
                    s.WhenStopped(h => h.Stop());
                });
                x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                x.SetServiceName("SimpleService");
                x.SetDisplayName("Simple Service");
                x.SetDescription("Simple serv description");

            });
            int exitCodeValue = (int)Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
            Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
        }
    }
```

I have attached myself to the service and after it reaches the line of `ShowDialog` nothing happens.

**Update**
I have also added a `Logger` to log all important events and so far , it seems the form opens but i can not see it:

**Logger**

```
public class Logger {
        private string path;
        public Logger(string logPath=Constants.PATH) {
            this.path = logPath;
        }
        private object @lock = new object();
        public void Log(string message) {
            string formattedMessage = "Date:" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "\tMessage:" + message;
            File.AppendAllLines(this.path, new string[] { formattedMessage });
        }
    }
```

The output of the file is :

```
Date:6/12/2019 11:19:13 AM  Message:Started
Date:6/12/2019 11:19:13 AM  Message:From Form constructor
```

Comment: Your form won't show on your desktop because of [Session 0 isolation](https://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#WhatIsSession0Isolation). It's probably visible on Session 0. What version of Windows are you using? Some allow you to switch to Session 0.

Comment: I am using `Windows 10` and you are right , this service has to run independently of the `User`. It works one instance per machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a world where Session 0 Isolation -- an important security measure to prevent [Shatter attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shatter_attack) -- is the law of the land, you should think very carefully about any design relying on service interaction.

A best practice is to restructure your solution to have:

1. A service that runs in the background, independently of the
   user
2. A conventional GUI application that interacts with the service and
   can be run by any user

Comment: So there is no way i can have one atomic process that runs a long running thread and a `GUI` ? More important than security in the current scenario is the distance between the `GUI` and the other `Thread`.So far they were two `tasks` in the same process.

Comment: Sure, you can create one atomic process that starts at boot and launches a GUI. Windows doesn't put any restrictions on that. Services are all about "long running" and they can happily create windows and other GUI elements.

Comment: However the trouble arises when you want someone to interact with the GUI from the long running process.

Comment: Who should see the GUI? Any person who logs on? Only the first person to log in? Suppose the first login is via RDP, do they still see the GUI? What happens if that first person logs out and a second person logs in? Does the second person see the GUI? As you can see, things get complicated real fast!

Comment: Furthermore, the single-process approach is crippled by a fundamental fact: Each process must reside inside a single session. A process started in Session 0 (the only sesion available at boot) cannot show a GUI in Session 1 (the one created when the first user logs in). This limitation constrains how services can interact with a user.

Comment: The service is supposed to open a pop-up at certain hours and if the user does not press the a button, the computer will shut down.So the process has to run across any user.The pop-up has to appear to whomever is logged-on at that hour.So yes i guess i should make this process reside in Session0 and communicate with a pipe with the GUI process that runs at that specific time ( specific session)